# Parse data from yaml file to dictionary and updating in Django models

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a yaml file, which I am parsing into a dictionary, as follows

```
   def parse(self):
        with open("/students.yml", 'r') as stream:
            try:
                return (yaml.load(stream))
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)
```

After parsing this file into a dictionary I am getting a large data in dictionary:

```
{
    u 'A101\ab0\ab0': {
        'NAME': 'RAZ',
        'AGE': '17',
        'ROLLNO': u 'A101\ab0\ab0',
        'CLASS': 'SIX',
    }, u 'A102\ab0': {
        'NAME': 'OM',
        'AGE': '15',
        'ROLLNO': u 'A102\ab0',
        'CLASS': 'SEVEN',
    }, u 'A103\ab0': {
        'NAME': 'PURI',
        'AGE': '15',
        'ROLLNO': u 'A103\ab0',
        'CLASS': 'SEVEN',
    }
}
```

I have created the Djangomodel for `name, age, rollno, class` field. I wanted to update models with the getting response after parsing.

What could be efficient way to create object and bulk update.

Comment: You need to update the entries and not create them, right? What is your primary key then? The `u 'A101\ab0\ab0'` etc.?

Comment: Yes, I need to update only. `A101\ab0\ab0` , `A102\ab0` , `A103\ab0` these are the primary keys for respective data.

Comment: AFAIK Django cannot do this natively in a single query, but you can use this module: https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update